# What does this error mean? (errorC2678) and how do I fix my code?

Tags: c++, class, methods, vector, boolean

My bool method here is supposed to be checking for the character "-" within a multidimensional vector saved as private object "sudoku_". It returns true if it finds a "-" and returns false otherwise. It's really straightforward, so I don't know why I'm getting this error:

"error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Here is my code:

```
bool Grid::checkiffull(){

 string selement = "-";

 if (find(sudoku_.begin(), sudoku_.end(), selement) != sudoku_.end())
      return true;
 else
      return false;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the private object definition:

```
vector<vector<string>> sudoku_;
```

The error is apparently in the "xutility" file, line 3026:

```
template<class _InIt,
class _Ty> inline
_InIt _Find(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, false_type)
{   // find first matching _Val
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
    if (*_First == _Val)
        break;
return (_First);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `sudoku_`?

Comment: remove the irrelevant stuff, and add the relevant one...

Comment: The nice things about the compiler error messages is that they include the *line numbers* of where the error are. I would guess that the line number of your error isn't anywhere in the code you show, mostly because the code you show doesn't have a `==` operator anywhere.

Comment: note: your return statement pair is an antipattern, you can directly return the result of the expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think it has: how else would you implement `find`? :)

Comment: To the OP, is that the *only* message you get? No context? No line number? Nothing else? Please edit your question to include the *complete* error output.

Comment: Okay, now we have some important context. `sudoku_` is a vector of vectors, and you try to compare each element in `sudoku_` with a string, which is impossible since each element in `sudoku_` is a *vector*.

Comment: Oh! Alright, I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable is a vector of a vector of strings:

```
vector<vector<string>> sudoku_;
```

When you call find, you are searching for a `string`, so you should call it on a simple `vector<string>`, not on a nested data type.

So you must first find the right item in the "external" vector, and then you can use your code on the "internal" one.